# Should a GTA 5 tag be made ready?

Tags: discussion, tags

Tomorrow, in the UK (I don't know about the RoW I'm afraid) the next instalment in the GTA series is released. In preparation for a flood of new questions should a GTA 5 tag be added (`gta-5`?) so that people who are unable to create new tags (too low score like myself) can ask questions early on?

Comment: When it *is* added I suggest we be proactive and make the top-level tag [grand-theft-auto-5], just like the rest of the titles in the series. (with [gta-5] as a synonym)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tags can't be created in isolation, they have to be created on a question. There is no question about GTA 5 right now (I assume), and posting any would be against our rules for unreleased games.

I wouldn't worry about this at all, if a user that can't create tags asks the first question about a new game, there'll be someone to add that tag in no time. We have a lot of high-rep users that can just edit and add the tag.

Comment: OK I didn't actually realise there was a rule about unreleased games (I did wonder why there wasn't any questions yet!). Hopefully there won't be many questions before the tag gets created!

Comment: @chris Typically people will just meddle with the tag field until their question goes through anyway.